# Magento 2 : Forms in Frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, forms

I needed to create configuration form in Magento2 admin. After research, I found that forms had to be defined in xml (system.xml)

```
    <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
        <label>Foo Configuration</label>
        <field id="foo2" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="11" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
            <label>Foo Email</label>
            <comment>Defines the foo email.</comment>
            <validate>required-entry validate-email</validate>
        </field>
```

I found this solution very "clean"

Now I need to make form in frontend, and all examples I find are defining form in phtml files :

like [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend)

Is there a way to create frontend form in xml also?
If yes, What is the best way?
If No, Why this difference?