# Magento2 Custom Form

Tags: magento2, forms

I would like to create custom forms that send the content to a predefined email address. How would I go about creating this? It is essentially the same as the default contact form but with different content.

Comment: go to link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140159

Answer (score 0):

create a custom email template based on contact mail template and edit it with your required form fields.