# Magento 2 - Custom contact form not showing up

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, contact-form

How would I create a secondary contact form in Magento 2.2? I'd like it to have the following fields:

- Name
- Phone
- Email
- Checkbox 1
- Checkbox 2
- Submit button

I have tried following this thread which does something similar, but couldn't get the module to display anything other than a 404 page: [Create Custom Form in Magento2 Frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend?rq=1)

Here's the code I have used based on the above example:

> app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="companymodule" frontName="companymodule">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_booking.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>HTML title - The booking form page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Booking" name="companymodule.booking" template="Company_Module::booking.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Company/Module/Block/Booking.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
            // companymodule is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

        return '/companymodule/index/booking';
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
     }
}
```

> app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/booking.phtml

```
<h1>Booking page</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" type="text">
    <input name="bookingTime" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Send booking informations">
</form>
```

> app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Booking.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I ran the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But I cannot get the frontend to show when going to .../companymodule/index/booking or .../module/index/booking

EDIT:

Big part of this issue was me not having Company/Module/registration.php and Company/Module/etc/module.xml file in place.

Comment: Please share all your code module

Comment: [![blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQfYg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQfYg.png) its not working blank page. please give me solution. its really helps me lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the :

> app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_booking.xml

to:

> app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/companymodule_index_booking.xml

**Update:**

**app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Booking.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    //add contructor
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
         Context $context,
         \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've renamed the file, flushed and re-compiled but unfortunately I still get a 404 page on /companymodule/index/booking

Comment: What you see if you type : yourdomaine.com/companymodule/index/booking ?

Comment: I get my store's 404 page

Comment: Look my update, you forgot to add the contructor

Comment: I was still getting a 404 error and realised I was missing the registration.php file. I've added it in and I can see the front-end now. I think it was your original answer that I required so I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks for your help.