# How can I create custom form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, forms

I want to create custom form for support in my Magento 2 website

So how can I achieve this with the use of only one file(.phtml)?
(All html and php code should be in one file)

It means I want to create only one file for this. Actually I have a support form in Magento 1 website but I don't know how to use this code in Magento 2

Comment: do you want to override contact form of Magento 2 and what will you do with the data that was filled by user ?

Comment: Yes  I want to override it and I want to get a mail of all data that was filled by user.

Comment: As far i know atleast you to overide few files like phtml for new fields and controller class to send a custom mail , i hope you already searched.


https://magenticians.com/add-custom-field-in-magento-2-contact-page/

Comment: Is it necessary to create module can't i create this form without the use of any additional files?

Comment: as far i know we must do in that way , after all you want to alter fields and email templates as well.

by creating a module it will just take an extra hour that's it,but you have more control.

if you found any other method you can post here as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow following link, in this link give clear understanding to creating simple form in Magento 2 front side.

[Magento 2 create custom form in Frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend)

Answer (score 0):

***Note: Change Vendor/Modulename as per your Module***

**Create the frontend router**

> /app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="companymodule" frontName="companymodule">
            <module name="Company_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Create the layout file in below path**

> /app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_booking.xml

Name of this file should be link module_controllername_classname.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>HTML title - The booking form page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Module\Block\Booking" name="companymodule.booking" template="Company_Module::booking.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Create the Block**

> /app/code/Company/Module/Block/Booking.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
            // companymodule is given in routes.xml
            // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
            // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

        return '/companymodule/controller_name/action';
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
    }
}
```

Create a template file

```
/app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/templates/booking.phtml

<h1>Lets Book You Slot</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" type="text">
    <input name="bookingTime" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Send booking informations">
</form>
```

**Create the Action Controller**

```
/app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Booking.php
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**NOTE: Run upgrade,di-compile commands and flush the cache**

Answer (score 0):

Have a follow up here: https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-form-in-magento-2-frontend/

Essentially what you are doing is updating code in form.phtml.