# Create a new registration form to customer magento 2

Tags: magento2, registration

I want to have 2 different forms according to customer group, so how to do so? And how to call a controller in form:

```
                <form method="POST">
                    <input type="radio" name="type_profile" value="local" checked> Client Local<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="type_profile" value="export"> Client Export<br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="create new account " />
                </form>
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    if(isset($_POST['type_profile']))
                    {
                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                        $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');

                        if($_POST['type_profile']=="local") {
                            $redirect->setRedirect('http://localhost/Selecta/customer/account/create/');
                            //echo "You have selected : local";
                        }else if($_POST['type_profile']=="export") {
                            //echo "You have selected :export";
                            $redirect->setRedirect('http://localhost/Selecta/customer/account/create2/');

                        }
                    }}
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call controller in form.

1. Add Form tag like this in phtml file:

   ```
   <form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
   ```
2. Add function in block file like this:

   ```
   public function getFormAction()
   {
     return '/companymodule/controller_name/action'
   }
   ```

For more details you can refer to this link: [How to Create Custom Form in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend)

Comment: thanks it seems to be helpfull t will test that

Comment: just one question how to do to enable customer from groups2 to register from this form is there something extra to do when creating the new form

Comment: nothing happened  so can you please explain more what to put in getFormAction and how to call the inscription form

Comment: You need to open your block file then add new function like getFormAction()  in that you have to return your action path like this (/your module/controller_name/action)