# Magento 2 : How to create custom Contact form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, custom, forms, contact-form

I am using Magento 2.3
As per my requirement. I have to create multiple form in my website

So can anyone provide me appropriate instruction for how can i create custom form like contact form

**Thanks**

Comment: If you need to create more than 2 forms pls use this plugin - https://codecanyon.net/item/custom-contact-form-for-magento-2/21702762

Comment: can you please tell me steps for how can i create custom form using custom programming.  thanks

Comment: Need custom front end form with submitted details displaying in admin panel grid?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you the exact solution as it sounds like you have specific requirements.  But you need to do something like the following

[How to Create Custom Form in Magento2 Frontend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend)