# Magento custom form with module Step By step by step

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms, html

I am new in this field...

and I want to learn...

Please help me how to create simple form in `Magento 2.0`.

Comment: Frontend form or admin form?

Comment: just follow this tutorials you will get you answer https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Comment: Custom Module front end Form - ranganathan

Comment: I am quite new to magento. Can you suggest a tutorial for using custom form frontend in magento? I checked this but couldn't find - Waqar Ali

Comment: Please have a look in this post, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend

Comment: hi thank you so much for this link but i have tried already its not working - MGento