# Custom controller goes to 404 for custom form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error, controllers, 404

I have created a custom controller to show a custom form but it goes to 404 page in Magento 2 ?

Controller file path : ( app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Index/Booking.php )

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $customerSession;
protected $urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession; 
    parent::__construct($context);
}
/**
 * Booking action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage("You must be logged in to view product");
        $this->customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->customerSession->authenticate();
        return;
    }
    // 1. POST request : Get booking data
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        // Retrieve your form data
        $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
        $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
        $phone       = $post['phone'];
        $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

        // Doing-something with...

        // Display the succes form validation message
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

        // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/companymodule/index/booking');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    // 2. GET request : Render the booking page 
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
}
```

My routes file path ( app/code/Company/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="companymodule" frontName="companymodule">
        <module name="Company_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

My companymodule_index_booking.xml file path ( app/code/Company/Module/view/frontend/layout/companymodule_index_booking.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>HTML title - The booking form page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Company\Module\Block\Booking" 
name="companymodule.booking" template="Company_Module::booking.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

My Block code path ( app/code/Company/Module/Block/Booking.php )

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Block;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

/**
 * Get form action URL for POST booking request
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormAction()
{
        // companymodule is given in routes.xml
        // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
        // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

    return '/companymodule/controller_name/action';
    // here controller_name is index, action is booking
}
}
```

I have followed this [How to Create Custom Form in Magento2 Frontend?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend) for that but 404 comes how to solve that error.
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Please share your block code

Comment: Updated please check @HarshJayswal

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller like this :

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   public function execute()
   {
       $this->_view->loadLayout();
       $this->_view->renderLayout();
   }
}
```

And then check does your URL is access or not.

Comment: It gives me an error on hitting url " Invalid block type: Company\Module\Block\Booking "

Comment: Confirm you are creating this block class : Company\Module\Block\Booking

Comment: Yes basically i want a custom form on froentend @Dhiren

Comment: I telling that confirm you are passing proper class in your xml and that block file is exist on the same location, because error is that that class not found.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion there is an mismatched class name in my Block file.
On submitting the form it goes to http://127.0.0.1/companymodule/index/booking and not found and on applying die on it it doesn't show there.will you please help me @Dhiren

Answer (score 0):

Please update the below files

> **Block**

```
<?php 
namespace namespace Company\Module\Block;


class Booking extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{   
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
}
```

> **Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
}
```

> **Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Company\Module\Block\Booking" name="booking" template="booking.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```