# Page keeps blank when creating a custom form. Controller and routes are set up correctly

Tags: magento2, layout, forms

I was following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125478/how-to-create-custom-form-in-magento2-frontend) but unfortunately, the form does not show up. Here is my complete module:

Mageplaze/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Mageplaze/HelloWorld/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get form action URL for POST booking request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        // companymodule is given in routes.xml
        // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
        // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

        return '/helloworld/index/index';
        // here controller_name is index, action is booking
    }
}
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Booking action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get booking data
        $post = (array)$this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname = $post['lastname'];
            $phone = $post['phone'];
            $bookingTime = $post['bookingTime'];

            // Doing-something with...

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Booking done !');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/hellworld/index/index');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the booking page
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
            <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Index" name="helloworld_index_index"
               template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml

```
<h2>Welcome to Mageplaza.com</h2>
<h1>Booking page</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
    <input name="firstname" type="text">
    <input name="lastname" type="text">
    <input name="phone" type="text">
    <input name="bookingTime" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Send booking informations">
</form>
```

**What happens?**
When opening the page `mysite.com/helloworld/index/index` Layout keeps blank. (Just the layout keeps blank. Rest of the site like header, menu footer works).

---

**What I tried?**
I was making sure that the controller and routes are correct. If I change following files to this:

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml

```
<h2>Welcome to Mageplaza.com</h2>
```

Then output is as expected: Welcome to Mageplaza.com

So the error must be in either `/Controller/Index/Index.php`, `/Block/Index.php` or `/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml`.

That's at least what I think!?

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Can look in /var/log/debug.log or /var/log/system.log if there are any critical errors?

Answer (score 0):

So the flow is: Controller -> Layout -> Block -> Template

1. First, you put the code into Controller, something like `echo 123; die;`, visit the route to check if your controller is working
2. Now that the controller is working, put the same debug code to your block, you can use one of these `_prepareLayout` or `_toHtml`
3. Now for the template, at the very first line of the template, put `<?= 123; die ?>`
4. If these above steps are working, do one more to make sure your template is using the correct `$block`, by putting `echo get_class($block)` in your template

I hope you get the idea how to debug the code now, you follow step by step in the flow. Let's say you've done all the above but your form is not working, then you need to check where you output the `action`, does your form's element has `name` attribute`...

Comment: Thanks for the debugging steps. It passes the first 3 checks! However, check 4 is giving me `Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Index\Interceptor`. That's not my block, isn't it? Name of my block is `helloworld_index_index` as defined in `/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml` or am I wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's your block, you can use it now to get data into your template

Comment: The reason you see `Interceptor` is because Magento uses it to make it work with plugin mechanism, you don't need to worry when you see that interceptor word

Comment: Ok, but then it passes all 4 steps. So where's the error? It should work, shouldn't it? I really don't understand.

Comment: Ok, now I put content of form into template. It shows. Next I put content into Block. Form disappears. So the error has to be into above code of the Block. Any idea?

Comment: You can just follow my (extra) steps above

Comment: Now as you said, the normal content is ok, but when you starting adding data from your block, then it stops working => It must have something with the code you add in the block, so you can check again by start with small code such as `$block->setTest('value')` and then in your template, you do `$block->getTest()`. It's all about `follow the flow/code`

Comment: Hm, I don't get it. There's not much in the Block which could cause the template to go blank, isn't it? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Ok, now I left out the complete construct method, and the form shows up. What's wrong with the construct and why do I need it anyway? This is so strange.

Comment: To get example, you can just search in Magento's code base, try to find some class that extend the Template block (because you are extending it, you want to see how other people, who also extend it, write code). To read about the error, you should enable error reporting in Magento (please google for that), and check your `var/log` folder to get detail about the error

Comment: So, at the end I figured it out and posted a complete answer. Overall, your answer wasn't very helpful and didn't really contribute to the actual problem since I already posted in my initial question that Block, Controller and routes were working correctly. However, your steps to debug are kind of helpful. I leave it that way, so thanks anyway.